# Error 'str' object has no attribute 'values' pops up when using json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

I`ve got the DataFrame with nested json inside the extra_data column

[My df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvqo.png)

when I try to use `pd.json_normalize(transactions['extra_data'])` I get a
`'str' object has no attribute 'values'` error.
Is there any way to solve this? The dataframe is taken straight from the database, so that`s not a csv file or something

Comment: How do you retrieve the dataframe from the database?

Comment: please, check [ask], show [mre] and also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632

Comment: I use mysql.connector for Python

Comment: Most likely `extra_data` is `str`, not deserialized JSON. try `df['extra_data']  = df['extra_data'].apply(json.load)`

Comment: Thank you! The following code worked just fine
`df['extra_data']  = df['extra_data'].apply(json.dumps)
df['extra_data']  = df['extra_data'].apply(json.loads)
df = pd.json_normalize(df['extra_data'])`

Comment: And I apologize for poor formatting, that`s my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: Then I will post as answer

Answer (score 0):

Most likely values in `extra_data` column are `str`, not deserialized JSON. try

```
import json

df['extra_data']  = df['extra_data'].apply(json.load)
df = pd.json_normalize(df['extra_data'])
```